# xpath expression count() fails with exception, Expression must evaluate to a node-set

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I am getting an exception: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

when I run this code that I am expecting to count the number of nodes, what I doing wrong?

```
var doc = new XPathDocument("contosoBooks.xml");
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

var expr = nav.Compile("count(//bookstore/book)");

var iterator = nav.Select(expr);
while (iterator.MoveNext())
{
    if (iterator.Current != null && !iterator.Current.HasChildren) continue;
    if (iterator.Current != null)
    {
        var childIter = iterator.Current.SelectChildren(XPathNodeType.Element);
        while (childIter.MoveNext())
        {
            if (childIter.Current != null) Console.WriteLine(childIter.Current.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

my xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bookstore>
  <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981-03-22" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
      <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>8.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1967-11-17" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Herman</first-name>
      <last-name>Melville</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>11.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="philosophy" publicationdate="1991-02-15" ISBN="1-861001-57-6">
    <title>The Gorgias</title>
    <author>
      <name>Plato</name>
    </author>
    <price>9.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Note: Thank you for the effords to help me. I came up with this solution:

```
var doc = new XPathDocument("contosoBooks.xml");
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

const string query = "count(//bookstore/book)";            
var expr = nav.Compile(query);

switch (expr.ReturnType)
{        
    case XPathResultType.Number:
        Console.WriteLine(nav.Evaluate(query));
        break;

    case XPathResultType.String:
    // case XPathResultType.Navigator:
        Console.WriteLine(nav.Evaluate(query));
        break;

    case XPathResultType.Boolean:
        Console.WriteLine(nav.Evaluate(query));
        break;

    case XPathResultType.NodeSet:
        var nodes = nav.Select(expr);
        while (nodes.MoveNext())
        {                      
            if (nodes.Current != null && !nodes.Current.HasChildren) continue;
            if (nodes.Current == null) continue;
            var childIter = nodes.Current.SelectChildren(XPathNodeType.Element);
            while (childIter.MoveNext())
            {
                if (childIter.Current != null) Console.WriteLine(childIter.Current.Value);
            }
        }
        break;

    case XPathResultType.Any:
        Console.WriteLine(nav.Evaluate(query));
        break;              

    default:
        Console.WriteLine(nav.Evaluate(query));                    
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Evaluate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/755fkf1e.aspx), not Select:

double count = (double)nav.Evaluate(expr);

Comment: +1 for the interesting detail that it returns a double - somewhat unexpected.

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
var iterator = nav.Select(expr);
```

expr must be an XPath expression returning a node-set. Your XPath expression is one which returns a scalar value, the count of book nodes.

Comment: What do I need to use instead?

Comment: @user800454: Instead, you need to read and practice. You shouldn't expect an answer to do completely your homework. No answer can fill the huge gaps of knowledge and experience that you only can fill. Read, Read, Read, ...

Answer (score 1):

Simply change to:

```
var expr = nav.Compile("//bookstore/book");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var expr = nav.Compile("count(//bookstore/book)");
Console.WriteLine(nav.Evaluate(expr));
```